# loop through pandas dataframe to compare string if matches append row's value

Tags: python, pandas

How can I achieve the following?

| mat_no | grades |
| --- | --- |
| uJ/2018/001 | A |
| uJ/2018/002 | C |
| uJ/2018/003 | B |
| uJ/2018/001 | A |
| uJ/2018/003 | C |
| uJ/2018/002 | B |
| uJ/2018/001 | D |

the above is my python pandas dataframe and here is my attempt:

```
result = [];
for stud in df_master: ## iterate through my dataframe
    if stud == "uj/2018/001": ## if matches; append the next value in the row
        result.append(stud)
    else:
        pass
print(result)
```

my expected outcome:

```
|:uJ/2018/001 |:A :  | :A  | :D|
```

or in a list

```
uj/2018/001 ['A', 'A', 'D"]
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

use boolean masking and `loc` accessor for filtering out result then track position by `groupby()`+`cumcount()` then `pivot()` and finally `reset_index()`:

```
out=df.loc[df['mat_no'].eq("uJ/2018/001")]
out['key']=out.groupby('mat_no').cumcount()
out=out.pivot('mat_no','key','grades').rename_axis(columns=None).reset_index()
```

output of `out`:

```
    mat_no          0   1   2
0   uJ/2018/001     A   A   D
```

**OR**

If needed in list format then use `query()` for filtering out result then `groupby()`+`agg()`:

```
out=df.query("mat_no=='uJ/2018/001'").groupby('mat_no')['grades'].agg(list).reset_index()
```

output of `out`:

```
    mat_no          grades
0   uJ/2018/001     [A, A, D]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the below command :

```
 my_output = df.query("mat_no=='uJ/2018/001'").groupby('mat_no')['grades'].agg(list).reset_index()
```